# UINavigationController with UITabBar live bytes

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, allocation

I have a navigation controller with 3 view controllers. The third view controller contains a UITabBar and each tab on the tab bar has its own separate navigation controller. When I'm pushing and popping view controllers on the tab bar navigation controllers, all allocations work fine. They rise and decline accordingly. But when I pop the navigation controller that hosts the tab bar (the third VC) back to the second view controller(a view controller without the tab bar) and then back to the third VC again (the one hosting the the tab bar), the live bytes grow to more than what they were before when previously on that same viewcontroller.

Is there something special I need to do when popping the from the tab bar back to the view controller without the tab bar???

Or any other thoughts

I'm using ARC

I also do not use a sub class of UITabBar to control the tab bar

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was pushing a uitabbarcontroller onto and navigation stack and from what I understand this is not possible.

So instead I start the app out with the uitabbar and display a separate navigation controller as a modal